# Angularjs push overwriting scope array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

Every time someone clicks on an answer and thus executes data-ng-click="addAnswer(questionId, 0)" the $scope.answers array gets overwritten. I am unsure why it is doing this.

Is it because every time the new template is loaded into  the $scope gets reset? If so, that wasn't the behaviour I had expected.

Thank you for any assistance.

index.html (abbreviated)

```
        <div id="q" class="cta1_content ugh" data-ng-controller="testYourself">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
```

test-yourself.html

```
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h1 class="text-center">{{question.name}}</h1>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 text-center yesno">
                            <a href="#/test/{{questionId+1}}" class="q" data-ng-click="addAnswer(questionId, 1)">
                                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center yesno">
                            <a href="#/test/{{questionId+1}}" class="q" data-ng-click="addAnswer(questionId, 0)">
                                <span class="cta_next"><i class="icon ion-close-round"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

app.js

```
var calculonApp = angular.module('calculonApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'calculonControllers',
  'ui.bootstrap.showErrors'
  ]);

calculonApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/test/:questionId', {
        templateUrl: 'app/partials/test-yourself.html',
        controller: 'testYourself'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/test/0'
      });
  }]);
```

controller.js

```
calculonControllers.controller('testYourself', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {

    $scope.quiz = [
    {name:"a", answer: [{0: '1.', 1: '2'}], weight:25},
    {name:"b", answer: [{0: '1', 1: '2'}], weight:25}
    ];

    $scope.question = $scope.quiz[$routeParams.questionId];
    $scope.questionId = parseInt($routeParams.questionId);

    $scope.answers = [];

    $scope.addAnswer = function(a) {
      $scope.answers.push({
        'question':$scope.questionId,
        'answer':a
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Why is the` href` defined for the `a`. Why do you want to navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a service to keep track of the anwers, yes you are correct when the route changes answers array will be overwritten.

```
calculonApp.service('AnswerService', function() {
    var answers = [];
    this.addAnswers = function(questionId, a) { 
        answers.push({
            'question':questionId,
            'answer':a
        });
    }
    return this;
});


calculonControllers.controller('testYourself', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'AnswerService'
  function($scope, $routeParams, AnswerService) {

    $scope.quiz = [
    {name:"a", answer: [{0: '1.', 1: '2'}], weight:25},
    {name:"b", answer: [{0: '1', 1: '2'}], weight:25}
    ];

    $scope.question = $scope.quiz[$routeParams.questionId];
    $scope.questionId = parseInt($routeParams.questionId);

    AnswerService.addAnswers($scope.questionId, a);
  }]);
```